# Arduino Uno no longer allowing me to upload my sketch

Tags: upload, ide, arduino

I’m trying to upload my sketch to my Arduino Uno but get the following error message:

```
avrdude verification error content mismatch.
```

Does anyone know what this means and what I need to do to fix this I can’t find anything online to fix this.

Yesterday I was programming with this without any problem. But when I plugged it into my laptop today and started programming, I found that I can’t upload anything.

My Arduino Uno appears in device manager and my sketch does compile normally but just doesn't upload to the Arduino Uno itself.

Comment: A) The fact that you took the arduino out of your locker is not relevant to the computer question B) what did you find when you googled the error message

Comment: not much my teachers havent gotten this error neither and its for my school project witch only has 3 weeks left i know this is a bootloader error but i dont know ho to fix it

Comment: and about the fact i took it out of the locker is only to tell i didnt do anything wierd with it and it was on 1 place overnight

Comment: I don't really have much of a clue as I have never encoutnered anything lke it, but judging by the 2  threads  I read, it looks like you either a)buy another arduino or B)  Buy a USBtinyISP (like $5) or wingoneer usbasp, and use it to fix the arduino

Comment: Also bear in mind that the day you die you may also say you didn't do anything weird the day before. But sometimes things fail.

Comment: hahaha thanks you are right with that i found something and i can reboot the bootloader with another arduino so i took my friends uno ill post the outcome when im done

Comment: just to check back in bootloading with a second uno isnt working til now i am getting the same error massage over and over again

Comment: Well the two threads I read mentioned buying a little device to do it, but given that you are at uni and have a project and so on, and computer issues can take ages.. Why not just ask your mum/dad/grandpa to give you money to get a new arduino uno? University costs thousands and this is a one off payment of like $20 or something.  It's peanuts for anybody that is working. There are probably some going for $5 on ebay. It's peanuts. It's a lot less than university books(back when students used books, I don't know if they do still)

Comment: @barlop That is really a dark bit of commentary. That said you really do state the reality of the situation: These kind of devices are cheap devices that could die for any reason. So always keep that in mind as well.

Comment: @JakeGould Well it gets darker, 'cos most of the time these things aren't dead(i'd be reluctant to declare something dead particularly when just not working right), but it's too much effort to fix(unless doing so for fun and with no time limit). Fortunately these things aren't conscious so it's not too dark. And in this case he has a deadline and it's cheap, so even if it is very fixable(given time and effort), it makes more sense to get a new one.  (and that's even if you still haven't given up on the not working one)

Comment: @barlop thank you as you mantion i have a time limit as so i have ordered a new one still thanks, and like you said its fixable i will try on my own time .

Comment: @nick re time limit, even quicker is buying one from a shop, t's probably cheap enough and widely available enough and by getting it from a shop you get it straight away and you won't get messed around by a late delivery